# Who is "TL" translator/commentator of Hovot Halevavot?

Tags: translation, faith-bitachon-emunah, hovot-halevavot

[Bitahon and Hishtadlut for livelihood](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30426/bitahon-and-hishtadlut-for-livelihood)

In the top answer they bring a quote from Hovot Halevavot with one sentence added at the end from "TL". Who is TL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation comes from [dafyomireview.com](https://dafyomireview.com/398), where you can find a glossary of sources:

> Abbreviations used in this translation:
>
> - MH - Manoach HeLevavos commentary by Rabbi Manoach Hendel (1540-1611)
> - **TL - [Tov HaLevanon](https://www.sefaria.org/Tov_haLevanon) commentary by Rabbi Yisrael Halevi (1700-1777)**
> - PL - Pas Lechem commentary by Rabbi Chaim Avraham Hacohen (1740-1815)
> - ML - Marpe Lenefesh commentary by Rabbi Refael Mendel (1825-1895)
> - LT - Lev Tov commentary by Rabbi Pinchas Lieberman (1929-2005)